# Mapper and Reducer are interfaces in Hadoop version 2?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Just a basic question.I know the Mapper and the Reducer are Interfaces in the Hadoop version 2. But still when coding I see examples using ***extends mapper or extends reducer instead of implements***.Is there a reason for this or are they being implemented as in the old version due to backward compatibility? Here is the link where I've been studying
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#MapReduce_-_User_Interfaces

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*` is the package you should use for Hadoop2, and those are not interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you are reading on that page that the Mapper and Reducer are interfaces for MapReduce2, but the source code on that page clearly uses classes. Keyword being `extends`.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
...
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper
...
public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer
```

It should be mentioned that the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer` **are** interfaces, but those are meant to be used for MapReduce1.

I think the purpose of re-writing the Mapper and Reducer as classes was to simplify class creation without using `extends MapReduceBase implements` like so

```
class MyReducer<K extends WritableComparable, V extends Writable> 
     extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<K, V, K, V>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response cricket_007.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when having a closer look at the APIs.
**org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce
Class Reducer** is for Hadoop2 where Mapper and the Reducer are Classes and **org.apache.hadoop.mapred Interface Reducer** was there in Hadoop 1 where they were interfaces which compiles in Hadoop 2 as well. It's just the difference between the old API and the new one that supports backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Yes -Mapper and Reducer were classes in HADOOP-1x and it has been enhanced to INTERFACE in later HADOOP -2x versions

EXAMPLE -CODE:

*In previous versions of HADOOP*

**public static class New_Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper{**

*In HADOOP-2x*

**public static class New_Map extends Mapper{**